# sorting options concerning dash when repeated authors?

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Suppose I am referring to some different references from the same author (both `book` and `incollection`) with `\footcite[]{Author:Year}`. One authors begins with "E" and the other with "K".

In the bibliography in the case of one author beginning with "E", on the first appearance his name is displayed fully and then in all subsequent appearances always with a dash.

But in the case of the other author there are several appearances of his full name, without dashes. In between the dashes are correctly displayed.

Therefore I have no idea, where the problem originates. I link to my `.bbx` files:

- http://algorhythmics.com/latexstuff/sm-002.bbx
- http://algorhythmics.com/latexstuff/authoryearmodsm.bbx
- http://algorhythmics.com/latexstuff/philosophy-standard.bbx

Here is a example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[style=sm-002]{biblatex}
   \bibliography{...here is my bibfile} 


\begin{document}

\footcite[]{Kittler:1985}
\footcite[]{Kittler:1986}
\footcite[]{Kittler:1990}
\footcite[]{Kittler:1993}
\footcite[]{Kittler:1993c}
\footcite[]{Kittler:1994}
\footcite[]{Kittler:2006}
\footcite[]{Kittler:1998}
\footcite[]{Kittler:2000}
\footcite[]{Kittler:2009}


\footcite[]{Ernst:2000}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2002}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2004}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2005}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2006b}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2007}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2007b}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2008}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2009}
\footcite[]{Ernst:2011}


\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}
\printbibliography[] 


\end{document}
```

[image: The Bibliography (output)]

Here is the bib file:

```
@book{Ernst:2000,
    Address = {Weimar},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Publisher = {VDG},
    Shorttitle = {M.edium F.oucault.},
    Title = {M.edium F.oucault. Weimarer Vorlesungen {\"u}ber Archive, Arch{\"a}ologie, Monumente und Medien},
    Year = {2000}}

@book{Ernst:2002,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Publisher = {Merve},
    Title = {Das Rumoren der Archive. Ordnung aus Unordnung},
    Year = {2002}}

@book{Ernst:2004,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Shorttitle = {Medienwissen(schaft) zeitkritisch},
    Title = {Medienwissen(schaft) zeitkritisch -- Ein Programm aus der Sophienstrasse -- Antrittsvorlesung},
    Year = {2004}}

@incollection{Ernst:2005,
    Address = {Z{\"u}rich/Berlin},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Booktitle = {Politiken der Medien},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Editor = {Daniel Gethmann and Markus Stauff},
    Pages = {77-88},
    Publisher = {Diaphanes},
    Title = {Die Medien der Polis. Kein H{\"o}hlengleichnis},
    Year = {2005}}

@incollection{Ernst:2006b,
    Address = {M{\"u}nchen},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Booktitle = {Klosterforschung -- Befunde, Projekte, Perspektiven},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Editor = {Jens Schneider},
    Pages = {163-182},
    Publisher = {Wilhelm Fink},
    Shorttitle = {Medienmonastik},
    Title = {Medienmonastik},
    Year = {2006}}

@incollection{Ernst:2007,
    Address = {Frankfurt am Main},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Booktitle = {Die Szene der Gewalt -- Bilder, Codes und Materialit{\"a}ten},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Editor = {Daniel Tyradellis and Burkhardt Wolf},
    Pages = {175-187},
    Shorttitle = {Zeit und Code},
    Title = {Zeit und Code},
    Year = {2007}}

@book{Ernst:2007b,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Publisher = {Kulturverlag Kadmos},
    Shorttitle = {Gesetz des Ged{\"a}chtnisses},
    Title = {Das Gesetz des Ged{\"a}chtnisses. Medien und Archive am Ende (des 20. Jahrhunderts)},
    Year = {2007}}

@incollection{Ernst:2008,
    Address = {Bielefeld},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Booktitle = {Sound Studies: Traditionen -- Methoden -- Desiderate. Eine Einf{\"u}hrung (Sound Studies Vol. 1)},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Editor = {Holger Schulze},
    Pages = {125-142},
    Publisher = {Transcript},
    Title = {Im Reich von $\Delta$t. Medienprozesse als Spielfeld sonischer Zeit},
    Year = {2008}}

@incollection{Ernst:2009,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Booktitle = {Zeitkritische Medien},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Editor = {Axel Volmar},
    Pages = {27-42},
    Publisher = {Kulturverlag Kadmos},
    Title = {Die Frage nach dem Zeitkritischen},
    Year = {2009}}

@incollection{Ernst:2011,
    Address = {Berkeley, CA},
    Annote = {Ernst, Wolfgang. ``Media Archaeography: Method and Machine versus History and Narrative of Media'' In Erkki Huhtamo and Jussi Parikka, Eds., Media Archaeology: Approaches, Applications, and Implications, Berkeley, Calif.: University of California Press, 2011): 239 -- 255.},
    Author = {Wolfgang Ernst},
    Booktitle = {Media Archaeology. Approaches, Applications, and Implications},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:21:27 +0200},
    Editor = {Erkki Huhtamo and Jussi Parikka},
    Pages = {239--255},
    Publisher = {University of California Press},
    Title = {Media Archaeography. Method and Machine versus History and Narrative of Media},
    Year = {2011}}

@incollection{Kittler:1993c,
    Address = {Leipzig},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Booktitle = {Draculas Verm{\"a}chtnis -- Technische Schriften},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Pages = {58-80},
    Publisher = {Reclam Leipzig},
    Shorttitle = {Die Welt des Symbolischen},
    Title = {Die Welt des Symbolischen -- eine Welt der Maschine},
    Year = {1993}}

@incollection{Kittler:1994,
    Address = {Amsterdam},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Booktitle = {Zeichen zwischen Klartext und Arabeske},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Editor = {Susi Kotzinger and Gabriele Rippl},
    Pages = {161-168},
    Publisher = {Rodopi},
    Title = {Vom Take Off der Operatoren},
    Year = {1994}}

@incollection{Kittler:1998,
    Address = {M{\"u}nchen},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Booktitle = {Geschichte der Medien},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Editor = {Manfred Fassler and Wulf R. Halbach},
    Pages = {255-267},
    Publisher = {Wilhelm Fink (UTB)},
    Title = {Gleichschaltungen. {\"U}ber Normen und Standards der elektronischen Kommunikation},
    Year = {1998}}

@incollection{Kittler:2000,
    Address = {Frankfurt am Main},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Booktitle = {Medien, Computer, Realit{\"a}t -- Wirklichkeitsvorstellungen und Neue Medien},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Edition = {{1. Auflage 1998}},
    Editor = {Sybille Kr{\"a}mer},
    Pages = {119-132},
    Publisher = {Suhrkamp},
    Title = {Hardware, das unbekannte Wesen},
    Year = {2000}}

@book{Kittler:2006,
    Address = {M{\"u}nchen},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Publisher = {Wilhelm Fink},
    Shorttitle = {Musik und Mathematik},
    Title = {Musik und Mathematik -- Band 1. Helleas. Teil 1. Aphrodite},
    Year = {2006}}

@incollection{Kittler:2009,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Booktitle = {Zeitkritische Medien},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:20:06 +0200},
    Editor = {Axel Volmar},
    Pages = {155-66},
    Publisher = {Kulturverlag Kadmos},
    Title = {Blitz und Serie -- Ereignis und Donner},
    Year = {2009}}

@book{Kittler:1985,
    Address = {M{\"u}nchen},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Publisher = {Wilhelm Fink},
    Title = {Aufschreibesysteme 1800|1900},
    Year = {1985}}

@book{Kittler:1986,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Publisher = {Brinkmann \& Bose},
    Shorttitle = {Grammophon, Film, Typewriter},
    Title = {Grammophon, Film, Typewriter},
    Year = {1986}}

@incollection{Kittler:1990,
    Address = {Weinheim},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Booktitle = {Zeit-Zeichen -- Aufsch{\"u}be und Interferenzen zwischen Endzeit und Echtzeit},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Editor = {Georg Christoph Tholen and Michael O. Scholl},
    Pages = {363-377},
    Publisher = {Wiley-VCH},
    Title = {Real Time Analysis -- Time Axis Manipulation},
    Year = {1990}}

@incollection{Kittler:1993,
    Address = {Leipzig},
    Author = {Friedrich Kittler},
    Booktitle = {Draculas Verm{\"a}chtnis -- Technische Schriften},
    Date-Added = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Date-Modified = {2012-04-10 20:19:16 +0200},
    Pages = {225-242},
    Publisher = {Reclam Leipzig},
    Title = {Es gibt keine Software},
    Year = {1993}}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with "Kittler, Friedrich 1993b"? For example, if it is "Kitt\-ler", where otherwise it is "Kittler", this could lead to two entries in the bibliography. (But in that case also the 1994-2009 entries must have another, third  "Kittler".) Could you check that code, please?

Comment: @Stephen Good catch, but there doesn't need to be a third sort of "Kittler" -- switching back to the first one is enough to produce effects similar to that shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @lockstep: For that case I had expected the entries to follow 1993a, but I did not test it. Thus, without a MWE, some "Kittler, Friedrich 1993b"-problem is the best guess I currently have.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Is it better now? Or do I need to export the .bib file?

Comment: @smiyazaki Please also add the relevant parts of your `.bib` file.

Comment: Added now the .bib file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `editorincoll` bibliography macro is the [problem again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51391/4483). Recall its definition from `sm-002.bbx`.

```
\newbibmacro*{editorincoll}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifuseeditor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{editor}}
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{author}{editor}\AND
                 \NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames[upshape]{editor}\addspace
        \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
```

The `\bbx@lasthash` command should expand to the `namehash` of the previous entry. It is used to identify recurring names in the bibliography for replacement by a dash. So `editorincoll` actually shouldn't alter `\bbx@lasthash`. Use the following definition instead.

```
\newbibmacro*{editorincoll}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifuseeditor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{editor}}
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{author}{editor}\AND
                 \NOT\iffirstonpage}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames[first-last]{editor}\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! This is great help. Just a small edit: It should be as the following, right? `\newbibmacro*{editorincoll}{% \ifthenelse{\ifuseeditor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{editor}} {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{author}{editor}\AND \NOT\iffirstonpage} {\bibnamedash} {\printnames[first-last]{editor}\addspace}% \usebibmacro{editorstrg}% \clearname{editor}}}`

Comment: What is `\bbx@lasthash` doing?

Comment: @smiyazaki Whoops. I was missing a closing brace. It's fixed now. As for your second comment, I tried to explain that in the answer. Before `editorincoll`, `\bbx@lasthash` holds the `namehash` of the *current* entry's `author`. The original definition of `editorincoll` changes the value of `\bbx@lasthash`. So a recurring `author` in the *next* entry in the bibliography wasn't being replaced with a dash.